# Common LIsp issue with Macros and variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have an assignment where I need to write a script using lisp.  I am having issues with passing variables

Here is the code.  Issues to follow:

```
(defmacro while (test &rest bodies)
   `(do ()
        ((not ,test))
        ,@ bodies)
) 
(defmacro += (var inc)
    `(print (eval var))
    ;(setf (eval var) (+ (eval var) inc))
)

(defmacro iterate (i begin end inc &rest others)
    (setf i begin)
    
    (while (<= i (eval end))
        ;(dolist (item others)
        ;    (eval item)
        ;)
       
        (print (list 'two i (eval end)))
        (+= (eval end) 1)
        (setf i (+ i inc))
    )
)

(setf n 5)
(iterate i 1 n 1
    (print (list 'one i))
    (+= n 1)
)
```

The first issue lies in passing the statements to the iterate macro.  When I try to run the commented out dolist, the print statement will throw an error when it comes to the variable i.  For some reason I can not get it to print using the macro variable i which has a value, but it seems to want to default to the global variable i which has not been set.  I get the error:

```
- EVAL: variable I has no value
```

The second issue is when I call the "+=" macro.  The value of end in the iterate macro is 5 as passed to the macro by use of the variable N which it is set to 5, however, when I pass it to the "+=" macro using the line "(+= (eval end) 1)" I can not get it to pass the value.  I tried removing the eval in the line "(+= (eval end) 1)" and when I try printing it with "(print (eval var))" in the "+=" macro, I get the error
- EVAL: variable END has no value

How would I solve these issues?

Comment: your ITERATE macro is wrong. It should generate code, but it doesn't. Then there will also be no reason to use EVAL.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: 'if you are using `eval` you are making a mistake'.  There *are* cases where `eval` is justified, but they are not common, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your first macro is basically correct. It generates code.

```
(defmacro while (test &body body)
  `(do ()
       ((not ,test))
     ,@body))
```

One can check it with an example. We expand the macro using example code. The function `MACROEXPAND-1` expands the top-level macro exactly once. You need to pass code to the function `MACROEXPAND-1`:

```
CL-USER 1 > (macroexpand-1 '(while (< i 10)
                              (print i)
                              (incf i)))
(DO NIL               ; NIL is the same as ()
    ((NOT (< I 10)))
  (PRINT I)
  (INCF I))
T
```

The generated code is a `DO` loop. Just like intended.

Thus we can use your macro:

```
CL-USER 2 > (let ((i 5))
              (while (< i 10)
                (print i)
                (incf i)))

5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
NIL
```

**Your other macros should be like that**

- they should generate code
- macro expansion of examples should show the right generated code
- the generated code should work

**Your macros should NOT**

- be using `EVAL`
- try to compute results other than code